# How to send the request parameter in SAML like SAMLRequest

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I wanted to send the `appid` which needs to be passed as a request parameter like `SAMLRequest` request parameter. Using Spring SAML I have integrated, but how to add an extra attribute as request parameter like `SAMLRequest` .

Below is the request that I want to send:

```
"SAMLRequest": encodedSamlRequest
"ID": "TEST"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to pass the `appid`? Generally, you don't want the IdP to necessarily know what the user is accessing at the SP (think health information). I would capture the user's requested URL, their session ID, and everything else I need, store it temporarily for a hash, and send that hash in the RelayState... On return, find the hash, get the parameters I care about back, and send the user on.

Answer (score 1):

By spec, the only actual attribute you can send in a SAML AuthnRequest is the "supposed" subject. However, you can also utilize RelayState - what you set in there as the SP *must* be passed back to you by the IdP without being touched.

Comment: Hi I have updated the question, I need to pass the above parameters to IDP otherwise it won't accept. SO, is there any aleternative

Comment: the IDP should be accepting only the SAMLRequest form field. all the necessary information should be within the encoded SAML request. you need to discuss with your IdP why they are requesting some sensitive information outside of SAMLrequest.